# What's the trouble with my ASP.NET MVC route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have some routes in my ASP.NET MVC application that handle redirecting of old urls. The URL I'm redirecting is:

```
contentSpanishContentList.aspx
```

Here's the route:

```
routes.MapRoute("RedirectLegacyContent1",
                "content{contentUri}.aspx",
                new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Content", contentUri = string.Empty, contentId = 0 });
```

The problem is it comes up as not found. I figured out that the problem is (in bold) contentSpanish**Content**List.aspx. What should I do to make this route work with this case?

Comment: What is the full URL you are requesting? That route is only going to match `<domain>/content{contentUri}.aspx`.

Comment: http://<domain>/contentSpanishContentList.aspx

Comment: They all work except when the name contains "Content".

Comment: And you have an action method on your RedirectController named "Content"?

Comment: yeah. I know it works in most other cases such as "contentSpanishContetList.aspx" or "contentSpanishConteList.aspx"

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined before this that perhaps are taking precedence?

Comment: Hrm. A tough one then. I'll attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Interesting. I can request `<domain>/contentSpanishContent.aspx`, but I cannot request `<domain>/contentSpanishContentList.aspx`.

Comment: Strange, that doesn't work for me. Anything without "Content" though..

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the format of your route; because 'content' as text is being repeated, the match is hitting more than once and something is blowing up.

Comment: Working on figuring this one out; Im thinking perhaps some kind of hack of the catch all route might work.

Comment: I tried "content{*contentUri}.aspx" but it didn't like it.

Comment: Will you use this route only for incoming requests or outgoing as well (like pointing `Html.ActionLink` at some of these pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two solutions

1. Rename your pages to not include the same constant string (in your case it's the word `content`).
2. Write a custom route that's able to parse your requests - all you'll have to override is the `GetRouteData` method. And if you're planning to only use this route for incoming requests (not generating any URLs in your views to point to any of these pages ie. using `Url.Action` or `Html.ActionLink`) then the easiest way would be to generate something like a `RegExRoute` which would be easy to write and also easy to resolve these kind of requests.

The fist one is simple, the second is universal.

Comment: #2 was it.
This helped: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Fiddler to look at what's happening. Is the 404 happening on the first request? Or is it happening after the redirect?
2. Install the [RouteDebugger package](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx) and see what it tells you.

Comment: oooo...route debugger, I like.